# What is the meaning of I wasn't living with heart at that time

Tags: formality

Please explain the meaning of "I wasn't living with heart at that time"

Comment: It has no meaning that I can see.

Comment: sorry, actually the setense is "I wan't living with heart at that time"

Comment: See defininitions 1.3 and 1.4 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/heart). It means I wasn't living with courage (alternatively, liveliness).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**heart**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85068?rskey=FTqUKK&result=1#eid1892185) in figurative contexts:

> - The heart considered as the seat of the emotions generally; a person's emotional nature (often contrasted with the intellectual or
>     rationalizing nature located in the head
> - The bodily organ considered or imagined as the seat of feeling,    understanding, and thought.
> - In the most general sense: the mind (including the functions of    feeling and volition as well as intellect).

As in your sentence:

"I wasn't living with heart (feeling, understanding, thought) at that time"

Comment: I don't think I would have interpreted the given sentence to mean that. In fact, I don't think I would have understood it at all - certainly not without a context.